# Include in a multivariate analysis a variable with a strong skewness in the distribution?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, distribution

Good morning,
I have a doubt. In building a model on R, where I have a dichotomous dependent variable (in the multivariate analysis I then use a logistic regression), I would like to use a variable that has distributional problems, though.
The variable in question is divided into three levels (0, 0.5, 1) and the distribution is as follows:

```
table(df$Var1)

  0  0.5    1 
296  276 1641
```

If I relate it to the dependent variable, the distribution is as follows:

```
table(df$DV, df$Var1)

      0 0.5   1
  0 140 112 604
  1   5  15 163
```

When I go to do the multivariate analysis, the result in both magnitude and statistical significance are very high.

```
Var1      2.33679    0.47071   4.922 8.56e-07 ***
```

same for odds ratios

```
    Var1
10.1442308
```

I cannot figure out whether this significance is due to the unbalanced starting distribution in Var1, or whether in fact the fact that such a high positive significance once related to the dependent variable is a robust finding, given the preponderance of Var1 = 1, DV = 0 compared to Var = 1, DV = 1 in the double entry table.